# How to use llvm.eh.sjlj.setjmp intrinstic function in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to insert the *llvm.eh.sjlj.setjmp* intrinstic function in my LLVM Pass. From the [documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html#llvm-eh-sjlj-setjmp), this function takes one argument which is a i8* pointer to a five word buffer that saves the current environment. I use the following method to create a global array as the buffer:

```
*ArrayType* jump_buf_type = ArrayType::get(IntegerType::get(M.getContext(), 8), 80);
GlobalVariable* jmp_buf_llvm = new GlobalVariable(M, 
         jump_buf_type,
         false,
         GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage,
         0,
         "jmp_buf_llvm");
```

The above method create a global array and the returned *jmp_buf_llvm* variable has type of [80 x i8]*

However, I'm having a hard time to get the i8* pointer. I want to pass the created array as argument of the *llvm.eh.sjlj.setjmp* intrinstic function. Any suggestion on how to get the i8* pointer from the array?

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I think you can use `getelementptr` to get the pointer to the first element.